# Why does my newly build PC box not support Miracast?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, gpu, miracast

I just built my new PC box, here is a list of some components which I think that might be related to this question:

- Motherboard:  [Gigabyte X570 Aorus Pro WIFI](https://www.gigabyte.com/au/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10/sp#sp)
- GPU: Gigabyte Windforce OC 11GB NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti
- CPU: Ryzen 7 3700X

But somehow, I cannot do the Miracast to connect to my Smart TV.

Here are my system’s details.

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 9/12/2019, 00:22:38
         Machine name: DESKTOP-EDDN71A
           Machine Id: {XXXXX}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
         System Model: X570 AORUS PRO WIFI
                 BIOS: F5 (type: UEFI)
            Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor              (16 CPUs), ~3.6GHz
               Memory: 65486MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 65486MB RAM
            Page File: 8078MB used, 67134MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
      Miracast: Available, with HDCP 
      Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported  DirectX Database Version: Unknown
       DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0329 64bit Unicode
```

### Display Devices

```
            Card name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
         Manufacturer: NVIDIA
            Chip type: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
             DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
          Device Type: Full Device (POST)
           Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1E07&SUBSYS_37AC1458&REV_A1
        Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
 Device Problem Code: No Problem  Driver Problem Code: Unknown

       Display Memory: 43790 MB
     Dedicated Memory: 11048 MB
        Shared Memory: 32742 MB
         Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
          HDR Support: Not Supported
     Display Topology: Internal
         Driver Model: WDDM 2.6  Graphics Preemption: Pixel   Compute Preemption: Dispatch
             Miracast: Not Supported by Graphics driver
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just built my new PC box, but I cannot connect wirelessly to my Smart TV, through Miracast.

Miracast is supported entirely by the GPU and the Wi-Fi adapter.  This means that the display driver for the GPU and the driver for the wireless adapter both must support Miracast.  The wireless adapter must also support Wifi Direct.

> Miracast is a graphic card standard. Miracast requires a display adapter which supports Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) 1.3 which to the best of my knowledge includes all current AMD and NVIDIA GPUs, it also requires and a Wi-Fi adapter that supports Wi-Fi Direct.
>
> I've noticed while NVIDIA claims support for WDDM 1.3 and Miracast, it turns out Nvidia actually cut support for Miracast back in 2016; meaning you'd need some of their older drivers and a card available in 2016 to make it work.

Source: [Does Ryzen support Miracast on Windows 10?](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/does-ryzen-support-miracast-on-windows-10.3340327/)

I can confirm (based on the fact I have the same exact card), that the current Nvidia drivers for the Nvidia 2080 Ti, **do not support Miracast.**  This means that since you do not have a GPU that supports Miracast, you will be unable to use Miracast, with the hardware you have.

```
    Card name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
    Manufacturer: NVIDIA
    Chip type: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
    Miracast: Not Supported by Graphics driver
```

It appears that Nvidia dropped support for Miracast awhile ago.  **Due to the fact, your `Ryzen 7 3700X` does not have a GPU there is absolutely no way to enable Miracast with the hardware you have.**

Source: [Miracast not supported with the latest driver?](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/194677/miracast-not-supported-with-the-latest-driver/)

> My system support Miracast with HDCP. Do you know how to enable it?

**You will be unable to enable it due to the hardware you have.**

Comment: Hi @Ramhound please see my updated part. My system support Miracast with HDCP. Do you know how to enable it?

Comment: I reverted the edit due to the quoted sentence being more valuable, and it would require to much work, to rewrite my answer.  It’s not entirely clear why the sentence was even removed.