# Screen casting to TV on Windows 10 Desktop?

Tags: display, screencasts

I have a Windows 10 Pro (64-bit (10.0, Build 18363) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)) Desktop computer that does not have any sort of Bluetooth device however I have a 802.11n Wireless LAN Card and I was wondering whether it is possible to screen cast, share, whatever to my smart TV which supports WiFi and Bluetooth screen sharing.
Upon opening the "Connect" App by Microsoft, I am treated to a lovely message which says "The device doesn't support Miracast, so you can't project to it wirelessly" which although is a clear enough message, I was wondering why or whether it was possible to share or duplicate my screen over WiFi as I do not have a Bluetooth card.
In my DxDiag output I do however have "Miracast: Available, with HDCP" which does show signs of hope however I am unsure on how to proceed as my TV still does not show up in my search when attempting to add a device.

Edit:
My machine:
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18363) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
Driver Version: 26.21.14.4587
Miracast: Available, with HDCP
My TV:
Model: 55UM7100PLB
LG using webOS

Comment: Please edit your question and ad the TV manufacturer and the exact model name. Also add the info what graphics card you use in your PC (Intel, AMD, nVidia, ... +  model) Also check if you have installed the latest graphics drivers for your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my newly build PC box not support Miracast?](https://superuser.com/questions/1481706/why-does-my-newly-build-pc-box-not-support-miracast)

Comment: Discussions within the comment section are not allowed. I won't be returning to this particular question, and will be flagging, any additional commentary directed towards me.  *I respectfully request that I don't receive any additional pings.*