# How to re-enable Miracast in the latest Windows 10 which I see in Game Bar

Tags: windows-10, xbox360, miracast

About 8 months ago, I posted a question asking [how to use Miracast in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1481706/why-does-my-newly-build-pc-box-not-support-miracast). The answer was with my hardware(because it's too new to have the Miracast, Miracast was only supported in the older devices) I wouldn't be able to do Mira Cast.

However, today with the latest Windows 10, I saw the functionality of "Cast to Device" which to me is the same thing with Miracast. And I have tried and it works. This functionality is in Game Bar ONLY.

[image: Cast to Device]

Then I tried to play movies with Windows Media Player and found there is no button to Cast to Device.

So my question is: **how can we enable the Cast to Device function everywhere?**

---

Update 1:

I right click the movie file and Did find the option : Cast to Device. (Good start)

Then after roughly 12 times try, I finally can see the movie on my LG TV.
[image]

**But the movie playing was always dropped from time to time, so I had to re-Cast to Device.**

So not sure whether this is a good solution or not. could we make this more stable?

Comment: `Cast to Device` has been around since 2015.  The application must support either Miracast or DLNA.  I suspect Windows Media Player does not support it.  SInce `Movies and TV` does support it.  I suspect you need [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/adapters/wireless-display-adapter-2/p3q-00001#devkit-highlights) to solve your problem.

Comment: You should be able to right-click on the meida file to "Cast to Device" provided you have one detectable.

Comment: What exactly is unstable?  Verify your PC and TV are connected to the same network and the signal strength is strong enough.

Comment: hi @Ramhound updated, see the highlighted sentence.